# No puedo enviar email en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

Estoy intentando enviar email en laravel, y me aparece el siguiente error

> Expected response code 250 but got code "553", with message "553 Relaying disallowed as

Es raro, porque si me funciona mandar mails cuando estoy logueado, pero si no lo estoy me sale ese error.

Probé cambiar el email driver a "mail" en vez de "smtp" pero ahi no recibo los emails. Estoy usando zoho email.

Answer (score 1):

Publica el código para ver si estas haciendo buen uso de los puertos y credenciales que zohomail.

Supongo que tienes habilitado el imap a la cuenta de correo, así que, si estas usando bien los puertos y todo está bien configurado, debe ser problema de Zoho y deberías contactarte con ellos.